# Why in Turbo C compiler sizeof(int) is 2 bytes and in gcc Linux compiler is 4 byte?

Tags: c, integer, sizeof, turbo-c

Why in Turbo C compiler `sizeof(int)` is 2 bytes and in gcc Linux compiler is of 4 bytes?

Comment: Don't use TurboC. It is obsolete, non-standard conforming, gives bad diagnostics and produces poor code. Use some good free software compilers like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). Consider installing Linux on your PC if you don't have it yet.

Comment: Why all these downvotes? It's legitimate question, isn't it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14159971/694576

Comment: @alk I don't get the down-votes for valid questions

Comment: I would answer if allowed. An `int` was originally supposed to be the native word size of the machine, and Turbo C produced code for 8086 and 80286 machines with no 32-bit instructions. There are, in fact, also GCC targets for Linux on 16-bit machines.

Comment: GCC keeps 32-bit `int` even on `linux-x86_64` for three major reasons: that’s a little faster (mostly due to more `int` variables fitting in the cache), it’s backward-compatible with 32-bit Linux, and `int` is not allowed to be longer than `long int` (any more). There’s a *lot* of legacy code out there that assumes `long int` is exactly 32 bits wide, improperly. With a few defunct exceptions in the last century, compiler writers for 64-bit UNIX-like OSes just gave in and kept `int` and `long int` 32 bits wide. (POSIX requires that there be a switch to make `long` as wide as a pointer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof(int)` is not a constant across all platforms.

It varies from system to system.

PS: Only sizeof object which is constant across all platforms is `sizeof(char)`

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(int)` varies from machine to machine (and sometimes from compiler to compiler).

Usually `sizeof(int)` represents the "natural" word width of the CPU. But If your compiler runs as x86 program on a x64 machine even this assumption breaks.

Comment: "*... `sizeof(int)` represents  ...*" 1st this is not true as you add yourself, 2nd this does not answer the question.

Comment: @alk Please see the word "Usually". Do you know many counter-examples?

Answer (score 0):

In **MSDOS** instructions codes are `16 bit | 2 Bytes`.

So, the maximum integer values would be `16bit` integers.

#### What I've analysed so far:

> The keyword `int` differs from compiler to compiler.
> **Turbo C** is a `16 bit` compiler so it compiles the code into a `16 bit` machine code for the processor!
>
> As we all know, a compiler will convert the code to a machine code in order to work.
>
> Same applies for **GCC**.

The computers we use today is either `32/64` bit.

---

A compiler should support the architecture to make any applications work.

- **GCC** is `32/64 bit` compiler. So, `sizeof(int)` is `4 Bytes`.
- **Turbo C** is `16bit` compiler. So, `sizeof(int)` is `2 Bytes`.