# C, Printing the size of character pointer in C

Tags: c

```
char a[]="hello";
char *p=a;
printf("%d",sizeof(p));
```

The expected output is 4 or 8 but the output we get is 2.

Using TurboC3

Comment: I tried it in my MacBook Pro, I get `8` result as expected. did you run it on your laptop or an MCU? I think if the CPU is 16bit, then you have the possibility to get `2`.

Comment: Dimly related (via comments): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180062/c-printing-the-size-of-character-pointer-in-c TurboC is old and does things in its own way. Try something else. Also, you should probably ask for %lu as the format specifier, not %d.

Comment: Check whether compiler has setting called "memory model" and if it exists - set it to Large to see `4` for result. Or simply change definition to `char far *p=a;`

Comment: The format for a `size_t` value is `"%zu"`. Turbo C probably doesn't support that, so convert to some time for which a format exists, for example `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof p);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly recommend "Assembly Language: Step by Step *by Jeff Duntemann*" (not the whole book, just the memory models' section).

Size of pointer depend on **how much memory it has to address**. You're expecting four bytes, that is 32 bits and it can address 4 Gigs of memory. When you'll do some research, you'll find that there was no 4 Gig memory in any personal computer at the time Turbo C was developed (eighties).

As there were no rams of that capacity (maximum was a few megabytes), and even after that, most of the aplications were too "lightweight" (for backward compatibility) for the newer `x86` CPUs and high-end hardware (including memory, of course), applications were given a part of that memory (64k for turbo c as stated by @Nadim). So, why bother making a pointer 4 bytes in size when you already know it's never going to use those last 2 bytes.